# Does tor or reveal ones email address

Tags: anonymity

Hi while I was browsing using tor, I clicked on aparticular site and it showed my paypal account name and my email address.The url starts with file:.....I dont remember the rest, am I secure? I am using tor over AVG secure vpn.

Answer (score 1):

`file:///` references a file on your computer.

Depending on this file and how you navigated to it, it's possible that if it was malicious that it deanonymized you. If it was downloaded outside of Tor and was loading resources that were unique to you over Tor and the link to the local file was provided to your specifically then it's possible that you were deanonymized. *However* it's probably harmless.

Tor doesn't reveal your email address unless you type it into it, since it doesn't know your email address.

Using Tor Browser with AVG, or any anti-virus, installed is *less secure* than using it without. Using Tor over AVGs *so-called* "secure" VPN is twice as bad. You should [stop using anti-virus](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/guide.md#anti-virus).